# NSURLSessionDownloadTask and retrying

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks, afnetworking-2

I am using the following code to download a file from the web. How do i structure the code (using blocks) such that, if it fails, it will be retried with a max of retrycount. Here is the code that i am using to download the file.

```
    NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:configuration];

    NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"urlstring"];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:myURL];

    [request setValue:token forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

    NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadTask = [manager downloadTaskWithRequest:request progress:nil destination:^NSURL *(NSURL *targetPath, NSURLResponse *response) {
        NSURL *directoryURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:NSTemporaryDirectory()];
        return [directoryURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
        } completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSURL *filePath, NSError *error) {
              //check here if error then retry using block ?
                if (!error)
                 {
                     //do something with the file
                 }
                 else
                  {
                       //retry download ??
                  }
      }
  }];
   [downloadTask resume];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a `retryCount` instance variable and set it to however many times you want to retry the network call. Then you could put all your networking code in a method with a custom completion handler. Your completion handler could be a block that takes a `BOOL` as a parameter and returns `void`. Then, in your networking code, create a local `BOOL` variable and set it to `YES` or `NO` based on whether the network call succeeded or failed. You'll run the completion handler argument within your networking code. Then the block (completion handler) that you send as a parameter to the method can "see" whether the local variable in your method was set to `YES` or `NO`. If it was `YES`, the network call succeeded, so do nothing. If it was `NO`, the network call failed, so check `retryCount`--if it's > 0, call the networking method again and decrement `retryCount`.

**UPDATE**

This should give you a rough idea...

```
typedef void (^CustomCompletionHandler)(BOOL); // Create your CustomCompletionHandler type

- (void)getDataAndCallCompletionHandler:(CustomCompletionHandler *)completionHandler {
    NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:configuration];

    NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"urlstring"];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:myURL];

    [request setValue:token forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

    NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadTask = [manager downloadTaskWithRequest:request progress:nil destination:^NSURL *(NSURL *targetPath, NSURLResponse *response) {

        BOOL success = NO; // Create local variable to keep track of whether network call succeeded or failed

        NSURL *directoryURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:NSTemporaryDirectory()];
        return [directoryURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
        } completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSURL *filePath, NSError *error) {
              //check here if error then retry using block ?
                if (!error)
                 {
                     success = YES;
                     //do something with the file
                 }
                 else
                  {
                     success = NO;
                     //retry download ??
                  }
      }
  // Get main queue and call completionHandler and pass success:
  // completionHandler(success)
  }];
[downloadTask resume];
}
```

You would call this method by doing something like...

```
[self getDataAndCallCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
    // If success == true {  
    //     Do whatever you need to
    // } else {
    //     Check retryCount
    //     If you need to, call getDataAndCallCompletionHandler: again
    // }
}];
```

Comment: is it possible to post an example ?  I understand the concept as well..but not sure how to try out...even a referral link would be fine.

Comment: @cableload I updated my answer and included a **very rough** example. Play with it.